# restcomm hello world project from Restcomm Client Android SDK 1.0.0 BETA3 error

Tags: android, android-studio, restcomm

I'm runnig the restcomm hello world project from Restcomm Client Android SDK 1.0.0 BETA3 I followed the steps mentioned in this answer [Mobicents Restcomm Hello-World Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510019/mobicents-restcomm-hello-world-implementation)

But when I dial I still have errors in the logcat
and I don't hear  the Restcomm instance associated announcement.
this the log content :

`02-22 10:27:19.912 31783-3951/com.telestax.restcomm_helloworld E/libjingle: webrtc: stereo playout is not supported
02-22 10:27:19.912 31783-3951/com.telestax.restcomm_helloworld E/libjingle: webrtc: failed to enable stereo recording
02-22 10:27:19.912 31783-3951/com.telestax.restcomm_helloworld E/libjingle: webrtc: (voe_base_impl.cc:364): Init: Failed to set agc to enabled: 0
02-22 10:27:19.912 31783-3951/com.telestax.restcomm_helloworld E/libjingle: webrtc: (voe_audio_processing_impl.cc:1007): SetTypingDetectionStatus: not supported
02-22 10:27:19.912 31783-3951/com.telestax.restcomm_helloworld E/libjingle: webrtc: (voe_audio_processing_impl.cc:1007): SetTypingDetectionStatus: not supported
02-22 10:27:19.912 31783-3951/com.telestax.restcomm_helloworld E/libjingle: webrtc: failed to enable stereo recording
02-22 10:27:19.912 31783-3951/com.telestax.restcomm_helloworld E/libjingle: webrtc: stereo playout is not supported
02-22 10:27:23.356 31783-4012/com.telestax.restcomm_helloworld E/libjingle: webrtc: (process_thread_impl.cc:31): TimeUntilNextProcess returned an invalid value -4
02-22 10:27:23.586 31783-31783/com.telestax.restcomm_helloworld E/RCConnection: onSipUAError(): error code: SIGNALLING_CALL_ERRORerror text: sendto failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
02-22 10:27:23.646 31783-3952/com.telestax.restcomm_helloworld E/libjingle: SetAudioSend: No audio channel exists.
02-22 10:27:23.926 31783-4005/com.telestax.restcomm_helloworld E/BufferQueue: [unnamed-31783-5] cancelBuffer: slot 5 is not owned by the client (state=0)
02-22 10:27:23.926 31783-4005/com.telestax.restcomm_helloworld E/BufferQueue: [unnamed-31783-5] cancelBuffer: slot 6 is not owned by the client (state=0)
02-22 10:27:23.926 31783-4005/com.telestax.restcomm_helloworld E/BufferQueue: [unnamed-31783-5] cancelBuffer: slot 7 is not owned by the client (state=0)`

Comment: Please share the configuration values for the RCClient.createDevice(). Also, please note that currently 3G/4G is not fully supported and might cause networking issues like this one. So please try to kill the App and try again with 3G/4G disabled if you used it.

Comment: facing the same issue. createDevice() has the following params
    params.put("pref_proxy_domain", "sip:<Restcomm-Instance-IP>:5060");
    params.put("pref_sip_user", "bob");
    params.put("pref_sip_password", "1234");
    device = RCClient.createDevice(params, this);