# Error android studio restcomm hello-word project

Tags: android, sip, voip, restcomm

When I'm trying to open "restcomm hello-world" on github but I always gave errors. I've solved some of them. Last error is :[Mobicents Restcomm Hello-World Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510019/mobicents-restcomm-hello-world-implementation)

I don't know how to solve this error.

```
D:\ProjectFilesAndroid\RestCommExample\restcomm-android-sdk-1.0.0-BETA4\restcomm.android.sdk\src\main\java\org\restcomm\android\sdk\MediaClient\PeerConnectionClient.java
Error:(841, 27) error: cannot find symbol method stop()
Error:(856, 27) error: cannot find symbol method restart()
Error:(889, 28) error: method createVideoSource in class PeerConnectionFactory cannot be applied to given types;
required: VideoCapturer
found: VideoCapturerAndroid,MediaConstraints
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:restcomm.android.sdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':restcomm.android.sdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with latest Restcomm Android SDK [release](https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk/releases/tag/v1.0.0-BETA5) that came out this month as it seems that you are using an old release (i.e. BETA4). If you still have issues please post back.

Best regards